# Selenium find second element by Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to `find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP']")` in python selenium , But i have 2 `Button` with that's class and i need the second one, so it takes me only the first one.
i've tried the code below

```
find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP'][2]")

find_element_by_xpath("//[button[@class='sqdOP']][2]")

find_element_by_xpath("//button[2][@class='sqdOP']")

find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP'[2]]")
```

None of above worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for this XPath expression :

```
find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='sqdOP'])[2]"
```

Just add `()` to get the second `button` element on the page which fulfill a specific attribute condition (`@class='sqdOP'`).

Side note : your second try (`//[button`...) is not a valid XPath expression. You can't start an expression with a predicate. You need an element name or a wildcard (`*`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath` to get a list of elements. Access a specific index in this list to get the required element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JavaScript executor

```
WebElement buttton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sqdOP")
driver.execute_script("arguments[1].click();",buttton)
```

arguments[1] means click on second element.